# PHP Multiregional Site - Mod rewrite - Read $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I would like te start a new PHP project, but I'm looking for some answers first before I start since I have little PHP experience.

Here's the case:

- I have a website which **targets multitple regions** in EU.
- I would like to use the **PHP $_GET variables to 'indicate' the region**. But at the same time I would like to have **clean url's**
- Vissitors from the Netherlands redirects to http://mywebsite.eu/nl/subject
- Visitors from Belgium redirects to http://mywebsite.eu/be/subject

I would like to use simple php $_GET  variables to include more information in the url. http://mywebsite.eu/subject.php?region=nl goes to http://mywebsite.eu/nl/subject 
http://mywebsite.eu/subject.php?region=be goes to http://mywebsite.eu/be/subject 
http://mywebsite.eu/subject.php?region=global goes to http://mywebsite.eu/subject

My questions: 
+ **How do I create the clean urls** from example above
 
+ How can i **retrive the GET variables from a cleaned URL** (reverse) from http://mywebsite.eu/nl/subject $_GET['region']
+ If you know a good way to figure out a visitors country code. Let me know :D

I hope my explanation makes sense. --I know there're lots of similar topics, but its  hard to find a topic matching my case--

Comment: You probably would benefit from using a framework to build your project. If you can, take some time to study about one or two. I would suggest the http://www.symfony.com framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the rewirte rules in you `.htaccess` file like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)/([^//]+)$ $2.php?region=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`$1` will contain the regions like nl,ar ... and `$2` will have the `subject` and will land to `subject.php?region=nl`

just `echo $_GET['region']` you will have the `nl`